# Write a list in r to an excel file

Tags: r, excel, file-io

I have a list containing 5 dataframes of different length. I want to write those dataframes in the same excel sheet.

I have already tried using `WriteXLS()` and `write.xlsx()` but could not get the desired result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example where `xlsx` package functions are used to write 5 different tables on the same sheet :

```
library(xlsx)

### create a sample list
set.seed(123)
theList <- list()

theList$df1 <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=sample(c('X','Y','Z'),5,T))
theList$df2 <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=sample(c('X','Y','Z'),3,T),c=sample(c('A','B','C'),3,T))
theList$df3 <- data.frame(answer=42)
theList$df4 <- data.frame(x=1:2,y=sample(c('I','J','K'),2,T),z='M')
theList$df5 <- data.frame(m=1.2345,n='foo')
###


wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet <- createSheet(wb,"SheetNameHere")

currRow <- 1
for(i in 1:length(theList)){

  cs <- CellStyle(wb) + Font(wb, isBold=TRUE) + Border(position=c("BOTTOM", "LEFT", "TOP", "RIGHT"))

  addDataFrame(theList[[i]],
               sheet=sheet,
               startRow=currRow,
               row.names=FALSE,
               colnamesStyle=cs)

  currRow <- currRow + nrow(theList[[i]]) + 2 
}

saveWorkbook(wb,file = "myXlsx.xlsx")
```

Result:

[image: Excel Snapshot]

Comment: Thank you very much for the code in detail. I tried this code but I am getting a java exception error when I use the addDataFrame function.  java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No constructor matching the given parameters. Any suggestions?

Comment: I could be a lot of things... which version of java and R are you using ? Is the last version of xlsx package ? It can be helpful having the whole exception message, can you post it ?

Comment: I have figured it now. Earlier I was working with data.frames in the list. It works for that. However, I was unknowingly trying this solution for vectors which was giving me this error. Thanks for your help.