# Append lines of text above EACH data frame in list when outputting

Tags: r, lapply

Let's say I have two datasets (in actuality, I have 6) that are pulled in as a list, and I run a series of functions on them, and then I need exported these as separate excel files, naming them by a subset of their filenames. Before exporting them, I want to add two lines of text, like "Report" and "Quarter." How do I do this? I've provided a screen shot of the template for what I want to do.

I'm getting the error that `Error in if (file.exists(file) & !overwrite) { : the condition has length > 1` But there is also a problem even before that, where the output of the second lapply statement `lapply(output_data, name_file` will just output a list of 0's. So the issues kind of seem two fold and there is clearly something I am doing wrong.

```
library(openxlsx)

res <- list(mtcars, iris)
names(res) <- c('mtcars', 'iris')

some_fun = function(dat, vars){
  dat%>%
    group_by('vars')%>%
    summarize(count = n())
}

name_file = function(dat, file_name){
  wb <- createWorkbook()
  addWorksheet(wb, 'raw')
  writeData(wb, 'raw', "CAR SALES REPORT:", startCol = 1, startRow = 1)
  writeData(wb, 'raw', dat, startCol = 1, startRow = 3)
  
  addWorksheet(wb, 'processed')
  writeData(wb, 'processed', "CAR SALES REPORT:")
  writeData(wb, 'processed', dat, startCol = 1, startRow = 3)
  saveWorkbook(wb, file = paste0(file_name, '.xlsx'), overwrite = TRUE)
}

output_data = lapply(res, some_fun, 1)
lapply(output_data, name_file, names(res))
```

This goes beyond my first question, but let's say I actually have two separate outputs from some_fun, so it is actually

```
some_fun = function(dat, vars){
  dat1 <- dat%>%
    group_by('vars')%>%
    summarize(count = n())
  
  dat2 <- dat%>%
    group_by('vars')%>%
    mutate(count = n())
}
```

How would I then insert the output from a list of dat1 into the raw excel sheet and the output from the list of dat2 into the processed excel sheet, below:

```
name_file = function(dat, file_name){
  wb <- createWorkbook()
  addWorksheet(wb, 'raw')
  writeData(wb, 'raw', "CAR SALES REPORT:", startCol = 1, startRow = 1)
  writeData(wb, 'raw', dat1, startCol = 1, startRow = 3)
  
  addWorksheet(wb, 'processed')
  writeData(wb, 'processed', "CAR SALES REPORT:", startCol = 1, startRow = 1)
  writeData(wb, 'processed', dat2, startCol = 1, startRow = 3)
  saveWorkbook(wb, file = paste0(file_name, '.xlsx'), overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm very confused. Your `header_print` function doesn't have a `res` argument input, not does it define an object named `res`, so why does it `return(res)`? This doesn't make sense. Then in your 2nd code block you don't use `header_print` at all, but something called `main_fun`. Are these the same?

Comment: Sorry--maybe disregard the first code block (I haven't worked with dataframes as lists with lapply much at all. Mostly I just want to include text above output for each data frame in the second code block. The main_fun is what is processing each individual excel sheet (and isn't included in this question because I thought it would make things more confusing). I could however include main_fun; it is just very long. My first thought was to include the header_print function in the main_fun, but then it seemed to be renaming the column headers.

Comment: Ah, now I see you got `header_fun()` from the function you link. They are using `cat()` to write lines to a file directly - this is possible to do using `cat()` with plain text files like CSV or TXT, but not with Excel files. I would suggest removing it entirely from your question.

Comment: Could you make your example reproducible? We don't have your files, and if your file-reading-in code works, and your `main_fun` works, they're not really relevant to your question. Just start us off with "I've got a list of data frames `res <- list(mtcars, iris)`" (using built-in data for illustrative purposes) and then go from there with a couple sample file names.

Comment: Okay, updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: This just went from being barely understandable to a great question, nice edits!

Comment: I don't think adding the line to the data frame will work - data frames need to be rectangular. But you should be able to write the line first, and then use `addDataFrame` with `startRow = 2` to append the data frame after your label. I don't have Java installed so can't use `xlsx` so can't test...

Comment: Thanks for this...are you talking about something like this: ```line = 'quarter' /
df <- data.frame(new = 'new') /
addDataFrame(df, line, startRow = 2)``` unfortunately that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your updated code above you have two lists you must join. I've used `mapply(SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`, but there are other ways to do this.

```r
library(openxlsx2)

# don't pollute any folder
tmp <- paste0(tempdir(), "/fun_with_lists")
if (dir.exists(tmp)) unlink(tmp, recursive = TRUE)
dir.create(tmp)
setwd(tmp)

# create lists
res <- list(mtcars, iris)
names(res) <- c("mtcars", "iris")

# aggregate function
some_fun <- function(dat, vars) {
  dat %>%
    dplyr::group_by("vars") %>%
    dplyr::summarize(count = dplyr::n())
}

# xlsx output function
name_file <- function(dat) {
  raw       <- dat[["raw"]]
  processed <- dat[["processed"]]

  wb_workbook()$
    # raw worksheet
    add_worksheet("raw")$
    add_data(dims = "A1", x = "CAR SALES REPORT:")$
    add_data_table(dims = wb_dims(x = raw, from_row = 3), x = raw,
                   with_filter = FALSE)$
    add_named_style(name = "Title")$

    # processed worksheet
    add_worksheet("processed")$
    add_data(dims = "A1", x = "CAR SALES REPORT:")$
    add_data(dims = wb_dims(x = processed, from_row = 3), x = processed)$
    add_named_style(name = "Title")$

    # write file
    save(file = paste0(dat[["name"]], ".xlsx"))
}


output_data <- lapply(res, some_fun)

# assign output list
res2 <- mapply(
  x = res, y = output_data, z = names(res),
  function(x, y, z) {
    list(raw = x, processed = y, name = z)
  },
  SIMPLIFY = FALSE
)

# create output
lapply(res2, name_file) %>%
  invisible()

# check output

if (interactive()) xl_open(dir()[[1]])
```

Comment: Thanks for this! as a followup question, let's say you want to add both the iris and the mtcars dataset names to CAR SALES REPORT: dataset_name_here. How would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

*(Updated after OP elaborated)*

You can use [digEmAll's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27460066/9406040) with `xlsx`:

```
library(xlsx)

line1 <- data.frame(x = "CAR SALES REPORT")
df_raw <- data.frame(mtcars)
df_processed <- df_raw[1:5, ]

# set up workbook
wb <- xlsx::createWorkbook()
sheet_1 <- xlsx::createSheet(wb, sheetName = "raw")
sheet_2 <- xlsx::createSheet(wb, sheetName = "processed")

# add sheet 1
xlsx::addDataFrame(
    line1,
    sheet = sheet_1,
    startRow = 1,
    col.names = FALSE,
    row.names = FALSE
)

xlsx::addDataFrame(
    df_raw,
    sheet = sheet_1,
    startRow = 3,
    col.names = TRUE,
    row.names = FALSE
)

# add sheet 2
xlsx::addDataFrame(
    line1,
    sheet = sheet_2,
    startRow = 1,
    col.names = FALSE,
    row.names = FALSE
)

xlsx::addDataFrame(
    df_processed,
    sheet = sheet_2,
    startRow = 3,
    col.names = TRUE,
    row.names = FALSE
)

# write file
xlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, file = "mtcars.xlsx")
```

[image: Excel table of 'mtcars' with two rows of text above]

Comment: Hi, so I found something similar to what you have above, but what I'm really wondering about now is how I act on both datasets to get the desired output. I've updated by question to reflect that. Thanks so much!

Comment: @James Easy-pease if I understood you correctly. Otherwise it would be very helpful if you could explicity write down / screenshot the data structure you're looking for in the excel file.